# Can't buil http request for WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication

I have tried plenty of codes to get through basic auth. via a C sharp code for WebDriver, but I am still unable to get through.
The only real and possible way was by sending a string with credentials like:                    `string formattedUrl = $"https://{username}:{password}@{websiteUrl}";`
Now I have played a lot of times with my code and ended-up like:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AdbCommandSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string adbPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe";
            const string edgeDriverPath = @"C:\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe";
            const string websiteUrl = "somehttpsurl/login";
            const string username = "u";
            const string password = "5";
            const string username2 = "B";
            const string password2 = "2";

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                UseCookies = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
            };

            LaunchEmulator(adbPath);
            WaitForEmulatorToBoot(adbPath);
            StartApp(adbPath);
            PerformTapActions(adbPath);
            await KeepSessionAliveAndLoginToWebsite(username, password, username2, password2, websiteUrl, edgeDriverPath, handler);
        }         static async Task KeepSessionAliveAndLoginToWebsite(string username, string password, string username2, string password2, string websiteUrl, string edgeDriverPath, HttpClientHandler handler)
        {
            if (handler == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid handler.");
                return;
            }

            string base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")
            );

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Create a single HttpClient instance for session management.
            using (var sessionHttpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                List<System.Net.Cookie> authCookies = new List<System.Net.Cookie>();
                try
                {
                    sessionHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Credentials);

                    response = await sessionHttpClient.GetAsync("somehttpsurl/login");

                    if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Session kept alive.");
                        authCookies.AddRange(handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("somehttpsurl/login")));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response == null
                                ? "Failed to keep the session alive. Response is null."
                                : $"Failed to keep the session alive. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");
                    }


                    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
                    options.AddAdditionalOption("ms:inPrivate", false);

                    using (IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeDriverPath, options))

                    {
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(websiteUrl);

                        // Apply the captured authentication cookies to the WebDriver
                        foreach (var cookie in authCookies)
                        {
                            driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Domain, cookie.Path, cookie.Expires)); // Make sure to replace 'cookie.Expiry' with the actual property containing the expiration date and time.

                        }

                        // Cast to IJavaScriptExecutor
                        var javascriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;


                        // Rest of your code...
                        var jsResponseContent = javascriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(@"
    var base64Credentials = arguments[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'somehttpsurl/login', true); // Use true for asynchronous request

    // Set the Authorization header with credentials (base64 encoded)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Credentials);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // Check if the request is complete
            if (xhr.status === 200) { // Check if the request was successful
                var responseText = xhr.responseText;
                // Handle the responseText as needed
                console.log(responseText);
            } else {
                // Handle errors here (e.g., xhr.status is not 200)
                console.error('Request failed with status: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send(null);
", base64Credentials);
```

I expect the url to be aviable and not only by sending a direct string which chengase url based on credentials used.
Because in next steps it will blocks an interaction with buttons and elements for communications with server/backend.